# USA: Is it legal to take naked non-abusive pictures of my child?

Tags: united-states, child-abuse, pornography

I was wondering if it's illegal to take pictures of a baby while he's naked, for example. I'm mostly asking for babies, but it would be nice to know what age is ok to do it.

Comment: Is a baby wearing only a diaper “naked”? I ask because if the baby is female, then her nipples would be visible but her other private parts would not be; I am not sure if that is relevant. (The question says “he”, but perhaps that word is being used generically.)

Comment: Compare with Lewis Carroll's photographs of [Evelyn Hatch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evelyn_Hatch#Relationship_with_Dodgson) Wikipedia isn't considered a pornography site. ¶ The real issue is the potential eventual embarrassment to the person in the photo.

Comment: @RayButterworth Not everyone agrees that Wikipedia is not a pornography site, or at least, not everyone agrees that Wikipedia is free of pornography. For example, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Criticism_of_Wikipedia#Sexual_content and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Watch_Foundation#Wikipedia.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it's legal. To be illegal, the photographs would have to be obscene or pornographic. Nude people, ordinarily photographed, doing non-sexual, non-excretory things are neither. However, I would strongly advise caution, particularly if you plan to display or share these photographs. There are [definitely cases](http://blogs.findlaw.com/law_and_life/2013/10/legal-to-take-post-naked-baby-pictures.html) of people who have been charged with sexual exploitation of a minor for sharing nude photographs of their children.

Comment: Cool. The fact that it's legal... stems from the fact that it isn't illegal? (sic), that there is no place in law where it says it isn't? Or how else? Thank you!

Comment: @Santropedro, basic principle of US law: if it's not explicitly forbidden, it's permitted.

Comment: @Mark Thanks mark that is very useful! What I'm left wondering is what exactly says the law about that. For example two cases 1) It says nothing 2) It says it's permitted. I want to know wich case it is in USA law.

Comment: @Santropedro It's a little bit of both. For one thing, you can look at the laws against sexual exploitation, child pornography, and so on to see what they do and don't cover. But court cases in the United States also set precedent, and you can look at precedent setting court cases both to see what the laws have been held to cover and not cover and also what has been held to be explicitly protected by the Constitution.

Comment: @Santropedro: The codification of Mark's principle can be found in The U.S. Constitution Amendments 9 and 10.  9 says that the rights enshrined in the Constitution are not the only rights the people have.  10 says that where the Constitution did not explicitly mention something, the Feds had no right to governence of that issue and must devolve the powers to the state or the individual (including who does have the right: states or individuals... al the Feds can do is say "not my problem, figure it out yourselves).+

Comment: @Santropedro:  Finally, the 14th Amendment contains language that blocks states from making laws that the constitution says the feds cannot make laws on (i.e.   First Amendment grants the people 5 core freedoms:  Freedom of Speech, Freedom of Religion, Freedom of Association, Freedom of Peaceful Assembly, and Freedom of the Press.   Since it's pretty clear "Congress shall make no law" the 14th amendment stops states from making laws that restrict those freedoms (this closed loophole is the reason for the Civil War... there was no mention of who regulatates Slavery, so it was a State's Right).

Comment: The cases described in the blog you linked to seem to be typical cases of people in authority taking enforcement action without actually examining the situation – which can happen to anyone, regardless of what they are doing (and the responsibility should be firmly placed with the authority figures, not those who were wrongly accused). Is there any specific reason that caution is warranted in this situation?